# Finding average case complexity with probability

Tags: probability, asymptotic-complexity

Lets say we have a string n, which can either be populated with "a"s or "b"s
ex: n = "aaabbbab", "ababababab" and so on.
and we define a function called

```
HalfA(n):
  count a = 0;
  for each i in n:
    if n == 'a'
        i++;
     if i >= n.length/2
       return true 
  return false
```

and if n has a uniform distribution, what is the average case complexity of halfA. Intuitively, I believe it to be len(n) but I'm not sure how to show this. And suppose a is more probable than b, and its not a uniform distribution, how do I calculate the average case then?

Comment: it's `len(n)`. in the absolute best case, every character is 'a'. In this case is would still be `O(len(n)/2) = O(len(n))`

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I get that its len(n) but I'm not sure how to show it. What if it was not a uniform distribution, and p(a) = .8 and p(b) = .2 or something

Comment: No matter which distribution you use, it will still take at least n/2 steps. And at most n steps. The distribution doesn't change much in this case.

Comment: A more interesting question, would be: "assume you have an infinite stream of characters, governed by distribution d. What is the time complexity to find n 'a's." Even in this case it's `O(n)` for all distributions(except for `p(a)=0`), but it's less intuitive

Comment: I agree that for best case, it doesnt matter what distribution it is, it'll take atleast n/2 steps to count n/2 times, but what about average case

Comment: Average case is bounded by best case, and worst case. Both of which are O(n). It then follows that average case is O(n). That is `worst <= average <= best`. Worst and best are n, so we get `n <= ? <= n`. ? can only be one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ANY distribution.

Best case: n = "a*".
This will take `len(n)/2` steps, so the best case is: `O(len(n))`

Worst case: n = "b*".
This will take `len(n)` steps, because you have to go through the entire array. So worst case is `O(len(n))`

Average case is bounded by best case and worst case. That is, `O(len(n)) <= average case <= O(len(n))`. It follows that the average case complexity is `O(len(n))`